# How get URL.createObjectURL(blob) to work in Safari

Tags: safari, html5-audio

The following code is triggered by a user clicking on a button. It works in Chrome and Firefox. It does NOT work in Safari (11.1).

```
const blob = new Blob([binary], {type: 'audio/ogg'});
const audio = new Audio();
audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob); 
audio.load();
audio.play();
```

The following code works in all 3 browsers:

```
const audio = new Audio();
audio.src = 'test.mp3'; 
audio.load();
audio.play();
```

So, the issue is with URL.createObjectURL(blob) in Safari. The Safari console.log error thrown by audio.play() is:

> Unhandled Promise Rejection: NotSupportedError: The operation is not supported.

If audio.play() is commented out, no error is thrown.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

for mp3 type, you should use mime type `audio/mpeg`.

```
let audioBlob = new Blob([blob], { type: 'audio/mpeg' });
audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);
```

Answer (score 3):

When creating the blob the type matters. when i set the type to wav, my code worked.

```
{type: 'audio/wav'}
```